# Best way to cut a pytorch tensor into overlapping chunks?

Tags: pytorch

If for instance I have:

```
eg6 = torch.tensor([
    [ 1.,  7., 13., 19.],
    [ 2.,  8., 14., 20.],
    [ 3.,  9., 15., 21.],
    [ 4., 10., 16., 22.],
    [ 5., 11., 17., 23.],
    [ 6., 12., 18., 24.]])
batch1 = eg6
batch2 = -eg6
x = torch.cat((batch1,batch2)).view(2,6,4)
```

And then I want to slice it up into overlapping chunks, like a sliding window function, and have the chunks be batch-processable. For example, and just looking at the first dimension, I want `1,2,3`, `3,4,5`, `5,6` (or `5,6,0`).

It seems [`unfold()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.unfold) kind of does what I want. It transposes the last two dimensions for some reason, but that is easy enough to repair. Changing it from shape `[2,3,3,4]` to `[6,3,4]` requires a memory copy, but I believe that is unavoidable?

```
SZ=3
x2 = x.unfold(1,SZ,2).transpose(2,3).reshape(-1,SZ,4)
```

This works perfectly when `x` is of shape `[2,7,4]`. But with only 6 rows, it throws away the final row.

Is there a version of `unfold()` that can be told to use all data, ideally taking a pad character?

Or do I need to pad `x` before calling `unfold()`? What is the best way to do that? I'm wondering if "pad" is the wrong word, as I'm only finding functions that want to put padding characters at both ends, with convolutions in mind.

---

Aside: Looking at [the source of unfold](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/8c0da1f5e95c749f33b4e6eca00ef5584341bbe3/torch/onnx/symbolic_opset12.py#L177), it seems the strange transpose is there deliberately and explicitly?! For that reason, and the undesired chop behaviour, it made me think the correct answer to my question might be write a new low-level function. But that is too much effort for me, at least for today... (I think a second function for the backwards pass also needs to be written.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation performed here is similar to what a 1D convolution would behave like. With `kernel_size=SZ` and `stride=2`. As you noticed if you don't provide sufficient padding (you're correct on the wording) the last element won't be used.

A general approach (for any `SZ` and any input shape `x.size(1)`) is to figure out if padding is necessary, and if so what amount is needed.

- The size of the output is given by `out = floor((x.size(1) - SZ)/2 + 1)`.
- The number of *unused* elements is `x.size(1) - out*(SZ-1) - 1`.
- If the number of unused elements is non zero, you need to add a padding of `(out+1)*(SZ-1) + 1 - x.size(1)`

---

This example won't need padding:

```
>>> x = torch.stack((torch.tensor([
            [ 1.,  7., 13., 19.],
            [ 2.,  8., 14., 20.],
            [ 3.,  9., 15., 21.],
            [ 4., 10., 16., 22.],
            [ 5., 11., 17., 23.]]),)*2)

>>> x.shape
torch.Size([2, 5, 4])

>>> out = floor((x.size(1) - SZ)/2 + 1)
2

>>> unused = x.size(1) - out*(SZ-1) - 1
0
```

While this one will:

```
>>> x = torch.stack((torch.tensor([
          [ 1.,  7., 13., 19.],
          [ 2.,  8., 14., 20.],
          [ 3.,  9., 15., 21.],
          [ 4., 10., 16., 22.],
          [ 5., 11., 17., 23.],
          [ 6., 12., 18., 24.]]),)*2)

>>> x.shape
torch.Size([2, 6, 4])

>>> out = floor((x.size(1) - SZ)/2 + 1)
2

>>> unused = x.size(1) - out*(SZ-1) - 1
1

>>> p = (out+1)*(SZ-1) + 1 - x.size(1)
1
```

---

Now, to actually add padding you could just use `torch.cat`. Although I am the built-in, [`nn.functional.pad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.pad), would work...

```
>>> torch.cat((x, torch.zeros(x.size(0), p, x.size(2))), dim=1)
tensor([[[ 1.,  7., 13., 19.],
         [ 2.,  8., 14., 20.],
         [ 3.,  9., 15., 21.],
         [ 4., 10., 16., 22.],
         [ 5., 11., 17., 23.],
         [ 6., 12., 18., 24.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

        [[ 1.,  7., 13., 19.],
         [ 2.,  8., 14., 20.],
         [ 3.,  9., 15., 21.],
         [ 4., 10., 16., 22.],
         [ 5., 11., 17., 23.],
         [ 6., 12., 18., 24.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Comment: Using `F.pad(x, (0,0,0,p))` did work, and is easier to read than `cat` (I'm guessing it is at least as efficient, too??). I used `p = (SZ - overlap) - 1`, which gives an upper bound for how much padding is needed: as `unfold()` throws the excess away, it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: Good, definitely use `F.pad` then, it's best to use built-ins instead of workarounds.